# Artifactory server error 500 in package view after uinstall XRay evaluation

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

We are using Artifactory PRO for years now - currently Artifactory 7.15.3.

After the evaluation of XRay3 we decided to not buy XRay. I tried to uninstall XRay according to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY2X/Uninstalling+Xray, as there is no uninstallation procedure for XRay 3.

After uninstallation of XRay we get a server error 500 in package view. I cannot find any useful hint in the logs. Is there someone out, who had the same problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Navigate to Artifactory UI --> Administration --> Sevices | Artifactory --> Advanced | config descriptor and check if <xrayConfig> exists as well as is there any header in Artifactory UI complaining about Xray not available? Also, confirm the OS on which Artifactory is installed?

Comment: i found the following in config descriptor:

    <xrayConfig>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <baseUrl>http://localhost:8046/xray/</baseUrl>
    <user></user>
    <password></password>
    <artifactoryId>default</artifactoryId>
    <xrayId></xrayId>
    <allowDownloadsXrayUnavailable>false</allowDownloadsXrayUnavailable>
    <allowBlockedArtifactsDownload>false</allowBlockedArtifactsDownload>
        <blockUnscannedTimeoutSeconds>60</blockUnscannedTimeoutSeconds>
    </xrayConfig>
....


We are running Artifactory on Centos7

Comment: there is another

            <xray>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </xray>

some lines below

Comment: sidenote: the Server Error 500 appears only for logged-in users